# Coupon Code API Params

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, coupon-codes

We just want to know what would be the json params to create coupon code from magento2 rest API. The API we are using to generate the coupon code is **/rest/V1/coupons**

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 1):

We can use http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#resource_salesRuleCouponManagementV1: **/V1/coupons/generate** to generate coupon for a rule:

Body JSON:

```
{
  "couponSpec": {
    "rule_id": 0,
    "format": "string",
    "quantity": 0,
    "length": 0,
    "prefix": "string",
    "suffix": "string",
    "delimiter_at_every": 0,
    "delimiter": "string",
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, it did help me out, is there any API where we can create New rule for coupon code in magento and pass the coupon code with name, expire date, status.

Comment: You should go here: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/ > salesRuleRuleRepositoryV1 > /V1/salesRules

Comment: @harish if my answer solved your issue, you can accept it as the solution.